# Server receiving packets after timeout TCP/IP

Tags: java, android, sockets, tcp

I am writing simple Server through TCP/IP for my android app.

I am facing a problem where server only receives messages after the timeout on the app.

My server side:

```
            System.out.println("Connection accepted");
            
            DataOutputStream outToClient = new DataOutputStream(connectionSocket.getOutputStream());
            capitalizedSentence = "READY";
            
            writeToUser(outToClient, "READY".getBytes());

            String response = readFromUser(connectionSocket); 
                // Server hangs on readFromUser();  
            
            if(response.contains("IL"))
            {
               byte[] bytes = DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary(foo);
               writeToUser(outToClient, bytes);
            }
```

App side:

```
            if (ack.equals("READY")) {
                ack = "";
                dataOutputStream.writeBytes(command);
                dataOutputStream.flush();
                
                buf = new byte[556];
                dataInputStream.read(buf);
                                    // app hangs on read() and gets timeout
            }
```

The problem is that, server receives command only after application gets read timeout.

My current scenario is this:

1. Connection accepted: Application receives "READY"
2. Application sends commands and tries to read response from server
3. Server is hanging on readFromUser() and only receives message after the app gets read timeout.

   Any ideas what am I doing wrong ?

**Update:**

The code works if I use readLine, instead of read(buf) ( if I understand clearly server hangs on read(buf) and is in waiting mode as socket is not closed yet even though no more data is beeing sent. )

However such way I have to add "\n" after each command, and server is only emulator, app works with different device who does not understand "\n" at the end and will crash.
Is there any way I could make this work without using readLine() ?

**Update 2**

```
   public void writeToUser(DataOutputStream outToClient, byte[] bytes) throws IOException 
   {
       outToClient.write(bytes);
       outToClient.flush();
       String s = new String(bytes);
       
       writeLog("Sent to client: " + s);
   }
   
   public String readFromUser(Socket socket) throws IOException, InterruptedException
   {
        writeLog("Reading...");
        
        BufferedReader inFromClient = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
        String clientSentence = inFromClient.readLine();
               
        writeLog("Received: " + clientSentence);
        return clientSentence;
   }
```

Above `readFromUser()` method works just as expected. But, this requires adding `"\n"` on each command sent from client app. And real device I have to communicate with does not understand `"\n"` and will treat the command as unrecognized... I am writing this server simply for testing purposes and I want it to be as close to real one as possible.

Previously I was just trying to get it done without `"\n"` on each command using `inFromClient.read(cbuf);` instead of `readLine()` and server always got hung on read, and received command only after socket was closed on client side. Even though I know that client sent the command and is waiting for response.

The question is how can I receive command without using `readLine();` and `"\n"` on client side.

Comment: How are you reading `ack` in the client? And are you sure the timeout isn't on reading the `ack`? It would make more sense to me.

Comment: No. Timeout is not on ack reading. Please look at update on question. The problem is that server is not receiving data. Well it is receiving data, but it hangs on read and waits for more data to come. And only after the socket is closed the command is retreived from read(buf).

Comment: So what do readFromUser() and writeToUser() do?

Comment: It hangs on read(buf) if the size of buf is more than the number of bytes that can be read. If your client sends 10 bytes then the server should not try to read 15 bytes from the stream. If the server does it will timeout if the client stays connected. If the client closes the connection right after 10 bytes sent then the server will immediately get the 10 bytes even if he asks 15 to read.

Comment: @greenapps Wrong. It hangs on read() if there is *no* data available to be read, and when there is, it copies that data and returns the count, whatever it is, from one upwards. The size of the buffer is irrelevant (except in the pathological case of zero). See the Javadoc for InputStream.read(), where this is all very carefully explained.

Comment: Well then why are you calling read() when there is no data available?

Comment: @greenapps Because he wants the data, and he is prepared to block until the data is available?

Comment: O I see now that you are not the OP. Well I suggest a test where at forehand the server knows that the client sent n bytes. The server declares a buffer of size n and does the read(). Client should at least flush().

Comment: @greenapps I suggest you test your own assertions before you post them, especially when they contradict the Javadoc. Your latest suggestion is pointless. Evidently you have never done any of this.

Comment: Well I hope the OP is clever enough to try it out.

Comment: @greenapps Why? Where's the benefit? How does it solve his problem? What's the point in carrying out a pointless suggestion? If anything was being received, he wouldn't be getting a read timeout at all, and he wouldn't be posting this question.

Comment: @Datenshi I don't understand your update. If `readLine()` works without a timeout, so will `read().` You still haven't posted the code I asked for, and until you do your question isn't answerable.

Comment: @EJP I have updated my question once more. Please take a look.

Comment: It is conceivable that the 'real' device server analyses its input byte-by-byte until it has identified a valid command, and so needs no command terminator because it assumes that the next byte is the first of the next command. I don't like such protocols because they are difficult to debug and maintain.  It's also posible that the device is TCP-broken and essentially unuseable.

Comment: Show the code of the version using read() which does not work.  Also consider running a packet sniffer on the server so that you can actually see each packet arrive, and its payload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'how can I receive command without using readLine(); and "\n" on client side'.  If you do not, or can not, want to use "\n" as a command terminator, then you must use another protocol to identify the start and end of the 'command' within the TCP octet/byte stream.

What protocol does your 'real device' server use to identify the start and end of commands?  If it uses a byte-by-byte state-machine to identify a valid command then you are going to have to duplicate that in your test server.

Comment: This is exactly what I was asking for. Sadly, I am not responsible for real device, and it works just as you stated. I guess there is no easy way to make my test server without "\n". My question was not very technical one.. But your answer is right. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You're reading lines but you aren't writing lines. So readLine() blocks until a line terminator arrives or the peer closes the connection.

Append a `\n.`

Comment: Well I am reading lines in server and writing lines to server. (code in question is only from server side) I am not reading lines in app and not writing lines to app. (this solution works without problems) The problem is that I was trying to make this as close as possible to real device communicator and remove readline() in server with simply read(). Please look at @Martin James answer he clearly got the problem I am facing. Your answer is technicaly correct, but you misunderstood my question. I am not very fluent in english and explaining, so sorry for that.

Answer (score -1):

Why not you increase timeout from APPs side. Or you can write a thread that will hit server in some interval for some time and if no response then show time out. This problem is in Apps side.

Comment: timeout is already 15000ms and the server instantly receives command the moment after app gets timeout. I know that problem is with the app, but I can't understand where.